# "future of [verb]" vs. "future of [noun]"

Tags: grammar

I have read "future of compute" as a slogan of some (non-english) IT company which feels quite wrong to me.  Instead I would have written "future of computing". So, what is right? Does "future of" always require a noun?

EDIT:
Note that I am generally interested if 'future of' requires a noun which I think is a valid question. Obviously the question came after seeing a special case where people seem to disagree whether or not 'compute' is a noun. Therefore, I do not feel like this is an off-topic question.

Comment: Slogans tend to have their own rules - memorable is better that grammatical.

Comment: Sounds like someone should have hired a better Martian-to-English translator.

Comment: Compute is now sometimes used as a [noun](https://www.quora.com/How-did-compute-become-a-noun-meaning-the-amount-or-existence-of-computation), for example Google has a "[Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/)" and sells "Compute Products".

Comment: As a slogan they can use whatever they want.  (I would have chosen "computifying".)

Comment: @HotLicks Computalyzing

Comment: As has been said, for a slogan you can use anything you like, but the phrase "future of computing" appears nearly everyday somewhere in the popular technical press. On the other hand I've never seen "future of compute" .

Comment: @Hot Licks Is the closeness to 'computrifying' intended?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it may be based on the assumption that 'compute' is never a noun (otherwise, it's POB whether slogans need obey any rules).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the phrase "future of" requires a noun to complete the prepositional phrase. The phrase "future of compute" is ungrammatical.

Comment: compute is a noun - it is specialized terminology. whether or not it sounds dumb is another matter

Comment: The specific term *compute* is an industry-standard term in the *specific* niche of virtualization software used by such companies as VMware, Microsoft, and Oracle. For whatever reason I can't understand, enterprise-level virtual environments  discuss *compute*, not *computing*. In normal English you would be right. But in that context, it's actually the reverse. (When I was a technical editor for VMware, I had to use *compute*, not *computing*.) In short *compute* is how fast the CPU is and how many cycles it devotes to a task. (As well as how many CPUs are assigned to a task.)